# When calculating the internal energy of a falling mass, why do Physicists use the unit of time local to the mass?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, gravity

Physicists calculate the internal energy of a mass that's falling towards the ground based on the local unit of time that changes as the mass falls to the ground. They conclude that it remains the same as it falls.
I agree that this is the case, because the dilation of the local unit of time keeps the period of the internal waves constant as the mass falls, which keeps its internal energy constant.

However, if I am lying on the ground under an apple tree when an apple falls, I'm not interested in how the energy of the apple changes according to its own unit of time, which is varying, I'm interested in how its energy changes in *my* unit of time, which is fixed. Calculating in my  unit of time, I find the periods of the internal waves of the apple are increasing as it falls, causing a reduction in its internal energy equal to it's gravitational potential energy change. That leads me to a much clearer understanding of what gravity really is.

So why do Physicists use local measurement of time, which hides the change in internal energy of a falling mass, and in doing so hides the most important effect of gravity?

Answer (score 1):

You may calculate in whatever frame of reference you wish, depending on what you're trying to understand. Experimenters tend to calculate in the lab frame: the complexity of an experiment is mostly in the machinery, so that makes it easier. Theorists prefer to ignore the machinery and focus on abstractions, which are often easier to understand in a different frame. Theorists are also more likely to author textbooks than experimenters, so there's a bias in physics education.

Comment: If that's the case then why is there a mystery surrounding gravity? According to my calculations, the driving effect of gravity is the gradient in internal energy that can be clearly calculated. The gradient causes a downward force which must be balanced by another upward force. In freefall that upward force can only be due to rate of change of momentum, leading to the acceleration due to gravity. Why does everyone say we don't understand gravity? I certainly do.

Comment: @AlanGee Your approach isn't terribly clear, but it seems to be some combination of Newtonian gravity with special relativity and quantum mechanics. Can it quantitatively model observed phenomena like gravitational lensing, Shapiro delay, the non-Keplerian nature of relativistic orbits, and gravitational radiation? Einstein's theory of gravity can do all that.